# Firebase accounts.signInWithIdp does not provide id token

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the `accounts.signInWithIdp` endpoint as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithIdp) to retrieve information about a user who has signed in using an identity provider (facebook, google, twitter).

When I perform a login, I expect to retrieve an `idToken`, which from my understanding is the token that is used to identify and verify the logged in user. However, I only receive this token when logging in with Google, not Facebook or Twitter. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that Google is a trusted provider and Facebook and Twitter are not, though I couldn't find any documentation about this.

My desired workflow is that the client makes a request to my server using the IDP credentials, and I give them back the `idToken`. The client can then use this `idToken` to make additional requests to my server, which verifies the token with Firebase on each request.

This is implemented this way because there is information specific to each user that is stored in my own database, not on Firebase. I identify the user in my database using their Firebase ID. Is my use case reasonable and if so why can I not receive an `idToken` for the user?

Edit:

The code I am using comes from the `firebase-php` library - specifically the `signInWithIdpAccessToken` function documented [here](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.9.0/authentication.html#sign-in-with-idp-credentials). The request uses Guzzle client to make the request. Here is a code snippet:

```
$uri = uri_for('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp');

$postBody = [
    'access_token' => $action->accessToken(),
    'id_token' => $action->idToken(),
    'providerId' => $action->provider(),
];

if ($action->oauthTokenSecret()) {
    $postBody['oauth_token_secret'] = $action->oauthTokenSecret();
}

$body = stream_for(\json_encode(\array_merge(self::$defaultBody, [
    'postBody' => \http_build_query($postBody),
    'returnIdpCredential' => true,
    'requestUri' => $action->requestUri(),
])));

$headers = self::$defaultHeaders;

return new Request('POST', $uri, $headers, $body);
```

When I print the response, I get this for a request using Facebook (some values redacted):

```
{
    "federatedId": "http:\/\/facebook.com\/...",
    "providerId": "facebook.com",
    "email": "...",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "firstName": "...",
    "fullName": "...",
    "lastName": "...",
    "photoUrl": "...",
    "localId": "...",
    "displayName": "...",
    "verifiedProvider": [
        "google.com"
    ],
    "needConfirmation": true,
    "oauthAccessToken": "...",
    "rawUserInfo": "...",
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyAssertionResponse"
}
```

But as you can see, no `idToken` field is provided.

Comment: ID tokens are available for all Firebase Auth accounts when using the provided Firebase APIs.  Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I have provided some code from the library I am using as well as the response I receive.

Comment: The response contains a `localId` field - you can use its value with the `signInAsUser` method to ensure that you get an IdToken https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.9.0/authentication.html#sign-in-without-a-token